# Conversion of period object with .to_timestamp() generates type error

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, plotly

I have a dataframe with dates (datetime objects) that I want to change to month and year (eg. 2021-04) only, in a new column df['month_year']. Intention is to use the month year values in the x-axis of a line plot in plotly express.

```
df['month_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Case Created Date']).dt.to_period('M')
```

The result is a period object, which seems fine:

```
28934    2021-04
23078    2020-09
23079    2020-09
23081    2020-09
23082    2020-09
Name: month_year, dtype: period[M]
```

But 'month_year' values can not yet be used as x-axis, i found out and the error is described here:
[modifying-extending-jsonencoder-for-panda-dataframe-timespan-objects](https://community.plotly.com/t/modifying-extending-jsonencoder-for-panda-dataframe-timespan-objects/5179)

So I extended it by

```
df['month_year'].to_timestamp(freq='M')
```

as per [Period to timestamp](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-period-to_timestamp/)

The result is a type error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-fb01a99cffce> in <module>
      2 print(df['month_year'].head())
      3 
----> 4 df['month_year'].to_timestamp(freq='M')
      5 
      6 #df['month_year_2'].head()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in to_timestamp(self, freq, how, copy)
   4921 
   4922         if not isinstance(self.index, PeriodIndex):
-> 4923             raise TypeError(f"unsupported Type {type(self.index).__name__}")
   4924         new_index = self.index.to_timestamp(freq=freq, how=how)  # type: ignore
   4925         return self._constructor(new_values, index=new_index).__finalize__(

TypeError: unsupported Type Int64Index
```

Does anybody know why the period object does not work with .to_timestamp()?
Thank you!

Update to comment below:
I have created a function which takes a df as argument.
The function then starts with:

```
    #Grouping
    group = df.groupby(['month_year', 'Case Sub Area'], as_index = False)['All Cases'].count()
    group = group.sort_values(by='month_year')
    group = group['month_year'].dt.to_timestamp()
```

I know that the last line is rubbish, but I could not get it running as intended (please see comment to your response below).

Comment: Can you show your whole code up to that point?

Comment: I have added it as "Update"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using .dt, since you are dealing with a series.

So instead of:

```
df['month_year'].to_timestamp(freq='M')
```

use:

```
df['month_year'].dt.to_timestamp(freq='M')
```

to change the whole column in-place:

```
df['month_year'] = df['month_year'].dt.to_timestamp(freq='M')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is one step ahead. Yet I wanted the column 'month_year' in the dataframe changed to timestamp. The suggested approach unfortunately creates a series of the column instead of just changing the column and keeping the dataframe.
Do you know how to keep the dataframe? I tried bracketing various ways but as expected, it does not work out.

Comment: I edited my answer. You have to replace the column in place as shown above.